# Makecab way to keep folder structure in .cab

Tags: windows, makecab

I am trying to keep part of the folder structure in a .cab file. Anyone knows what is the right way to make it?
    For example,

I want to make my.cab, in my.cab: kb_32\filtr.Inf, and filtr.sys

But I can only get my.cab ( unzip it and see C_\Users\EK\Desktop\dr\pcab\kb_32\filtr.inf and filtr.sys)

```
.OPTION EXPLICIT    ; Generate errors
.Set CabinetFileCountThreshold=0;
.Set FolderFileCountThreshold=0;
.Set FolderSizeThreshold=0;
.Set MaxCabinetSize=0;
.Set MaxDiskFileCount=0;
.Set MaxDiskSize=0;
.Set CompressionType=MSZIP;
.Set Cabinet=on;
.Set Compress=on;
; Specify file name for new cab file;
.Set CabinetNameTemplate=kb.cab;
; Specify the subdirectory for the files. 
; Your cab file should not have files at the root level,
; and each driver package must be in a separate subfolder.
.Set DestinationDir=C:\Users\EK\Desktop\dr\pcab;
; Specify files to be included in cab file;
C:\Users\EK\Desktop\dr\pcab\kb_32\filtr.Inf;
C:\Users\EK\Desktop\dr\pcab\kb_32\filtr.sys;
```

(Please be noticed that ; at the end of lines is only added here for make it look like correct code format for posting my question. sorry for my lack of experience of editing my code here.)

Thanks a lot!
LJ

Answer (score 2):

To define a directory structure in the target .CAB file, use `.Set DestinationDir` for each subfolder:

```
...
.Set DestinationDir= ;
C:\Users\EK\Desktop\dr\pcab\root.inf

.Set DestinationDir=kb_32
C:\Users\EK\Desktop\dr\pcab\kb_32\filtr.Inf
C:\Users\EK\Desktop\dr\pcab\kb_32\filtr.sys
...
```